# UBUNTU: why my crontab isn't running the code?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I've configured manually the `/etc/crontab` to add an event that runs on day 9 every months...

The Cron is running, but it didn't runned my code yet...
My code is at the **last** line:

```
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
23 9    9 * *   root    wget "http://www.mysite.com/url.api?dowhat=mensalcheck" --no-cache --read-timeout=1600 -O "/var/log/mysite.com/$(date "+url-api.%d-%m-%y.log")"
```

Comment: Canonical Answer for troubleshooting crontab: http://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure your cron is run, use "**crontab -e**" or "**sudo crontab -e**" to edit your cron jobs. Then when you're done editing and saved the file, crontab will install the new cronjob properly to be executed the next time.

So, use **sudo crontab -e** and make sure you at least do one modification to the file.

**Also** cron usually has **no PATH variable**, meaning it does know where to find **wget**, so the best is to put **/usr/bin/wget**.

Comment: crontab -e doesn't edit /etc/crontab

Comment: `cron` usually has a minimal PATH, rather than no PATH, but it is a good idea to fully specify directory names.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `cron` sees the percent signs as special. It converts them to newlines. You need to escape the percent signs to make them work normally.

```
23 9 9 * * root wget "http://www.mysite.com/url.api?dowhat=mensalcheck" --no-cache --read-timeout=1600 -O "/var/log/mysite.com/$(date "+url-api.\%d-\%m-\%y.log")"
```

If you check your log file or root's email, you should see error messages complaining about the problem.

Comment: Or better yet, put your command in a simple shell script, and then call the script from the cromtab.

Comment: +1, excellent answer.