# crontab -e on Red Hat 4.1.2-48

Tags: redhat, cron, mysql

The following command on crontab does not work at all.

```
0 12 * * * mysqldump -hserverhpost -uuser -ppass db > /path/to/backu/$(date +%d-%m-%Y)
```

I read extensively about this and i cannot see what is wrong with it.

I doesn't seen to work at all.

If i run the mysqldump command alone on the shell, it works fine, but when i send to crontab it doesn't.

Am i missing something?

I want it to run everyday at noon.

**Edit:**

The problem is:
The dump file is not created. the command alone is supposed to store the mysqldump on a file on a folder. which works fine when i run it on the shell, but it doesn't create the file on crontab.

Comment: It'll be hard to even start helping of you don't tell us what doesn't work, what output you get etc...

Comment: The dump is not created. the command alone is supposed to store the mysqldump on a file on a folder. which works fine when i run it on the shell, but it doesn't on crontab

Comment: So what happens instead? What's in the cron mail? What's in the cron logs?

Comment: i'm on a shared host, so i don't have access to those. 

I just asked for support from the hosting company, and they said they don't allow for mysqldump on crontab. is it possible to block the command only on the tab?

Comment: But they allow shell access?????

Comment: If you had searched extensively you'd most likely have found several resources that would point out the two most obvious problems with the crontab entry you show. Take a look athttp://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it which has info on how to debug this.

Comment: If you're just hobbying on a shared host, your question is off topic for Serverfault as it doesn't appear to relate to servers/networking or desktop infrastructure in a professional environment. It may be on topic for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) but please [search](http://superuser.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker Actually [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better choice, I think.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>%</kbd> is a [special character for cron](http://www.hcidata.info/crontab.htm). You have to escape it (<kbd>\%</kbd>). It should not prevent cron from working thought. Just the name of the the backup won't be the one expected, and be overwritten each day.

Answer (score 4):

Try to give the full path to `mysqldump`. In many systems, `cron` has a very limited `$PATH` compared to regular users or `root` and `mysqldump` might not be in cron's `$PATH`.