# mysqldump not working/running via cron job

Tags: debian, cron, mysql

I have a crontask which runs at 1am every morning and dumps all databases.

```
0 1 * * * /var/backups/dumpit.sh 2>&1>> /var/backups/dumpit.log
```

The `dumpit.sh` source:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u user -ppass --all-databases | gzip > /var/backups/mysql_`date +%u`.sql.gz
```

The script runs okay when executed manually but fails when run via the cron. Nothing is added to the `dumpit.log` file. Do I need to turn on logging in my `.myc.nf` file? Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Work your way through this http://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it. If that's the full extent of your crontab (or it's the last line) ensure there is a newline at the end of it.

Comment: @Iain, thanks. I have tested the cron and it is working fine. I think it is related to the `cron runs your command in a restricted environment.` section. However I am using absolute paths, and I thought by adding `#!/bin/bash` it would be able to run the `/usr/bin/mysqldump` command.

Comment: Doesn't the `sql.gz` file get created at all? As it is now, `dumpit.log` will always be empty. If you want to redirect standard error to `dumpit.log` you need to move `2>&1` to the end of the line like this: `>> /var/backups/dumpit.log 2>&1` or simply: `2> /var/backups/dumpit.log`, since `gzip` sends *all* standard output to `mysql_`date +%u`sql.gz`.

Comment: @jaume `sql.gz` doesn't get created. Do you mean my cron entry should be either: `0 1 * * * /var/backups/dumpit.sh >> /var/backups/dumpit.log 2>&1` or `0 1 * * * /var/backups/dumpit.sh 2> /var/backups/dumpit.log`?

Comment: Use `0 1 * * * /var/backups/dumpit.sh 2>> /var/backups/dumpit.log` instead. `>>` appends standard error to the file. Now `/var/backups/dumpit.log` should record any errors and give you a hint of what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Error was logged as `/bin/sh: /var/backups/dumpit.sh: Permission denied`. So I updated permissions for `dumpit.sh` to: `-rwxr--r-- 1 root root ` which worked.