# How can I create cron jobs in specific files on Linux Centos

Tags: linux, centos, cron, cron.daily, incrontab

I want to have a separate folders for `cron` jobs like:

`/mydata/cronjobs`

Now in that folder I want to have files like `backup_server` which will have the content like:

```
30 3 * * 1-5 /home/user/scripts/backup.sh 
30 3 * * 1-5 /home/user/scripts/backup2.sh
```

Similarly, I want to have more files in that directory for each separate `cron` job so that I can centralize and separate the `cron` jobs from one folder.

How can I make root run those jobs for all files in that folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](http://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put your files in the `/etc/cron.d` directory.

Comment: this requires you put root after the time in the file, like 

`30 3 * * 1-5 root /home/user/scripts/backup.sh `

Comment: can i symlink the folder in `cron.d`

Comment: @PetterH why i need root for that

Comment: @PetterH i added the file in there and backup was meant to be completed but cron did not execute

Comment: because you said "How can I make root run those jobs for all files in that folder?" and putting stuff in the folder @Michael said "/etc/cron.d" requires you specify a user to run each job.