# Run CURL every 5 seconds

Tags: centos, unix

I'm very new to linux and not sure what the best solution would be for the following.

I want to run a HTTP GET request every 5 seconds. I imagine some kind of service that I can start/stop at will.

I'm not bothered about the response, as long as the web server is hit. So I can throw away the response.

What's the best way to do this? I'm using a CentOS based VPS.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why in the name of everything unholy do you want to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670328/cron-running-cron-every-1-second

Comment: I'm pinging a web-service to start a background job at fixed interval times - exactly every 15 minutes of the hour 00:15, 00:30 etc. So I ping a PHP script that determines if it's time to run, and runs if so.

Comment: Please edit that (extremely relevant) information into your question :-)

Comment: why can't you just 'ping' it every 15 minutes ?

Comment: Because then that depends on being started at exactly 00:15, 00:30, 00:45, or 00:00 of the hour.

Comment: @MeshMan: I agree with @Iain here. Sounds like a perfect candidate for a `cron` job that runs every fifteen minutes. If you really need to do something every five seconds, this sounds like a candidate for a loop in a bash script with a five-second sleep.

Comment: You're right guys. I was thinking of CRON in a different way. I can take that logic out my server now so it simplifies the whole process - win win. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're Doing It Wrong.

> I'm pinging a web-service to start a background job at fixed interval times - exactly every 15 minutes of the hour 00:15, 00:30 etc. So I ping a PHP script that determines if it's time to run, and runs if so

Which means what you really want to do is `Run a task exactly every 15 minutes of the hour`.

You should be using `cron` for this, but not the way you're thinking.  You want to either:

- Create a crontab entry like `*/15 * * * * /command-to-run` on the server where you want the job to run.

or alternatively

- Create a crontab entry like `*/15 * * * * wget http://script-to-start`on some remote server with a reliable clock.

(If `*/15` isn't what you want `15,30,45` probably is -- that excludes the top of the hour).

Refer to [any decent `crontab(5)` man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5) for more details.

Comment: For the alternative solution, I'd use curl instead of wget and direct stdout and stderr to /dev/null: `/usr/bin/curl "http://example.com/script" 2>/dev/null`

Comment: @MeshMan A more complete and detailed explanation of cron/crontab, including how the `/` does its magic, can be found [on this question/answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/449651).