# How can I check cron task it's running?

Tags: linux, cron, scientific-linux

I put a cron script in `/etc/cron.d`:

```
[root@node ~]# cat /etc/cron.d/reconfig
0 */6 * * * root /root/bin/reconfig.pl
```

But I get no list of cron tasks for root:

```
[root@node ~]# crontab -l
no crontab for root
```

How can I check it's running ok?

It's a Scientific Linux 6.4 node.

Comment: If you work your way through http://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it it will give you valuable knowledge on cron and will undoubtedly help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[root@node ~]# crontab -l
no crontab for root
```

It displays this message because crontab -l list entries from user crontab and you edited just global crontab. If you want to edit users crontab just use this command:

```
crontab -e
```

To verify that your task has been executed just grep syslog:

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```