# crontab not outputting to log when cronlocks removed on some files

Tags: cron

I'm running a variety of crontab curl requests and I'm not sure why SOME of them stopped outputting the contents to log files. The only change I made was removing cronlocks from all of the entries since they were really pointless for me and a pain to manage.  In my testing, I've noticed that when I put them back for the entries that are failing, they work again.  What is the problem?

Please note, that I have removed file extensions through .htaccess.  If you need any other info, please let me know!  Thanks for your time!

Here's one that works properly:

```
00 6 * * * /usr/bin/curl -sS http://thisismysite.com/updater?no_header=1 >> $(date "+/home/jborn/thisismysite.com/cronlogs/\%Y\%m\%dlogUPDATER.txt") && mutt -s "UPDATER" -a $(date "+/home/jborn/thisismysite.com/cronlogs/\%Y\%m\%dlogUPDATER.txt") -- me@email.com
```

Here's one that doesn't output to the file like it did with cronlocks:

```
2 3 * * * /usr/bin/curl -sS http://thisismysite.com/mw?sp_ids=21,22,23,24,25,26&no_header=1 >> $(date "+/home/jborn/thisismysite.com/cronlogs/\%Y\%m\%dlogMIDWEST.txt")
```

I didn't want to leave pertinent info out, so here's how it was (working) with cronlocks:

```
2 3 * * * /usr/local/bin/setlock -n /tmp/cronlock.3783699908.155536 sh -c $'/usr/bin/curl -sS http://thisismysite.com/mw?sp_ids=21,22,23,24,25,26&no_header=1' >> $(date "+/home/jborn/thisismysite.com/cronlogs/\%Y\%m\%dlogMIDWEST.txt")
```

Comment: Please review http://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it it will almost certainly help you solve the problem or help you to gather more information that will help us to help you. In particular a gander at stderr would be good.