# Cronjob screen PHP does not executed

Tags: php, debian, cron, gnu-screen

If I execute the following in the terminal it works:

```
screen -dmS tt-rss-daemon sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/php /usr/share/nginx/www/tt-rss/update.php --feeds --daemon
```

If I write the following in a Crontab (*crontab -e*) and restart the machine nothing happens.

```
@reboot screen -dmS tt-rss-daemon sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/php /usr/share/nginx/www/tt-rss/update.php --feeds --daemon
```

Have anyone an idea how to correct this?

Comment: Work your way through http://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it is will help ypu solve your problem or at least help you gather information that will help us help you.

Comment: rather than a cron problem, it might just be a problem of requiring some enviroment variables that aren't set up in a non interactive shell. What is suggest you is to first add a line to your crontab that will just create a file with random content. This was you'll know if your cronjobs start correctly. Second thing, redirect the script's output to a file, so you'll see if anything happens. Also check the mail spoor for your user and for root, most systems send a mail to the user if a programs outputs something in stderr.

Comment: I suspect screen might be failing due to the lack of a TTY.

Answer (score 0):

is cron set to run when the system boots? Try setting it to run at a specific time, and see if it runs. If not, then odds are cron isnt running and you will need to add cron to start on the relevant run-level

in Redhat:

```
chkconfig cron on
```

in Gentoo:

```
rc-update add cron default
```

in Debian/Ubuntu

```
update-rc.d cron defaults
```

Failing that, most distributions have a script that is run on boot.
In Redhat distributions its in

```
/etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

In Gentoo

```
/etc/local.d/anyfilename.start
```

In Debian I believe you have to create your own init script.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `sudoers` file and make sure you do not have `requiretty` enabled (look for a line like `Defaults requiretty`).  `requiretty` prevents sudo from being used in cron and other non-interactive situations.  It isn't the default in Debian.  I am fairly certain `cron` should be emailing your user with the error message if that's the case (unless it's configured not to, or you sent the output to `/dev/null`).

Another option is if your user does not have permission to have a personal `crontab`.  In that case, `cron` would just ignore your entry completely.  If `/etc/cron.allow` exists your user must be listed in it. If `/etc/cron.deny` exists, your user must not be listed in it.