# Looking for simple scp script. SSH keys already set up

Tags: linux

I have a remote server and a local server. I am trying to automatically transfer a nightly backup on the remote server to my local one. SSH keys are setup, so no password is required.

Using the following command, it works manually:

`scp -r -P {REMOTEPORT} user@serveripaddress:/home/remoteuser/directory /home/localuser/directory`

I would like to set a cronjob so the previous action runs, but I am new to writing actual scripts. Is there a simple script that would make this happen?

Comment: you probably just need to prepend scp with '/usr/bin/' for this to work as a script.  Although I recommend rdist as the best tool for doing this.

Comment: You got a nice round answer below, but I recommend the simplest approach: just run that same line (albeit with a full pathname to the scp command) from cron, and you will be ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a simple script, let's say `backup.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/scp -r -P {REMOTEPORT} user@serveripaddress:/home/remoteuser/directory /home/localuser/directory
```

Make it executable with `chmod +x backup.sh`

Then, edit crontab (`crontab -e`) and set it up :

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/backup.sh > /var/log/backup.log 2>&1
```

---

Also, you could run it directly from cron (`crontab -e`) :

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/scp -r -P {REMOTEPORT} user@serveripaddress:/home/remoteuser/directory /home/localuser/directory > /var/log/backup.log 2>&1
```

ps : if you run into troubles, for sure we can help, but i strongly recommend reading this for debugging : [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)

Comment: OK, so I can run simple command line actions directly in crontab. What is the last part you added to the original command:  `> /var/log/backup.log 2>&1`

Comment: @Eric It redirects ok messages (if any) and error messages (if any) in a log file. Also you can use `>> /var/log/backup.log 2>&1` to append messages to the log file and not overwrite it each time. It could be a good idea to log command execution to check if everything went right !