# hg pull from Bitbucket fails when run from cron

Tags: cron, ssh-keys, mercurial

I have a local copy of a Bitbucket repo on one of my servers (under the user rob), and I created a script that runs every hour in cron and attempts to pull & update the local copy. The issue I'm having is that `hg pull` fails, even though when I follow the same procedure outside of cron it works fine.

I setup an ssh key for accessing Bitbucket in the normal fashion (i.e. [followed the guide in the Bitbucket docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678)) and then the repo was initially cloned with

```
cd /home/rob
hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/robjohncox/tools
```

The update script at `/home/rob/bin/update_tools.sh` is:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /home/rob/tools
hg pull >> /tmp/update_tools.log
hg update >> /tmp/update_tools.log
```

And the crontab for user rob is:

```
0 * * * * /home/rob/bin/update_tools.sh
```

All very simple. However, when the job runs, we see that the call to `hg pull` fails with the output

```
remote: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Does anyone have an idea why this may be happening - is there some other step that I need to take so that when cron runs it has access to the relevant public key? The `update_tools.sh` script runs fine from a shell.

Comment: What is the location and name of your private key ?

Comment: It's /home/rob/.ssh/id_bitbucket (sorry should have mentioned it wasn't id_rsa)

Comment: I hope I'm not arming you with the knowledge required to hack my server :)

Comment: To be honest I don't think this is a cron specific issue but work your way through http://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it - it will help you gather information to help us help you.

Comment: Thanks Iain - someone found a fix to the problem, but that answer you linked looks very valuable, I will go study

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try specifying the ssh command explicitly e.g.

```
hg pull -e 'ssh -i /location/of/key'
```

Cron runs with a minimal shell, so won't have access to your ssh-agent process because the SSH environment variables aren't set.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding sometimng like the following to your ~/.ssh/config file

```
Host example.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_bitbucket
```

to tell ssh to use a different key for the relevant server.