# logwatch on Centos 6.4

Tags: centos, cron, centos6.4, logwatch

My logwatch is configured correctly and is working correctly when I issue manually

```
/usr/sbin/logwatch
```

I added it to root's crontab and it is listed correctly when I make `crontab -l` which gives:

```
0 5 * * * /etc/cron.daily/0logwatch
0 2 * * * /usr/sbin/logwatch
0 3 * * * /etc/cron.daily/one_of_my_scripts
0 4 * * * /etc/cron.daily/another_script
```

My scripts work great but logwatch is not working although I added it twice in crontab using a direct call and using the script that is prepared to be run from cron.daily

/var/log/cron seams not to log per-user crontab activities

Any clues?

Comment: You realize that there is > 1 location where these type of service crons are located right?  Have you checked these as well?

Comment: Sorry, I can't get your point.

Comment: Work your way through http://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it it will help you gather information that will either solve your problem or help us help you.

Comment: Thank you. I followed the link and set the MAITO variable and knew where the problem comes from. sendmail is under /usr/sbin which is not  enabled by default for crontab entries

Answer (score 0):

I followed @lain's link (thanks @lain), set the MAILTO variable, waited for the report email which let me know that the problem comes from sendmail which is located is under /usr/sbin which is not  enabled by default for crontab entries. I just adjusted the PATH and everything is alright