# Shell script only executes partially when run with CRON

Tags: bash, cron, shell

I've written a shell script that does the following:

- Retrieve mail from a POP3 account (using GetMail)
- Save a copy of that email to S3 (using AWS CLI)
- Email me the filesize of the email

The script runs *fine* manually, and technically *runs* from CRON, but it only seems to be sending the email. The getmail and S3 bits don't seem to run.

Everything I've read seems to hammer home the message that I need to be careful about relative paths and the like when using CRON, but I *think* I'm using absolute paths everywhere I need to be, so I'm stumped as to what the issue could be.

My Shell Script is here:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run GetMail
getmail -r /PATH/TO/EMAIL/getmail.email

# Save to S3
aws s3 cp /PATH/TO/SCRIPT/email-backup.mbox s3://XXXXXXXXXX/email-backup.mbox 

# Send Confirmation Email

SUBJECT="EMAIL SUBJECT"
EMAIL="My@EMAIL.COM"

# Get current filesize
FILENAME=/PATH/TO/SCRIPT/email-backup.mbox
FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s "$FILENAME")

# Email Content
EMAILMESSAGE="/tmp/emailmessage.txt"
echo "EMAIL BODY" >$EMAILMESSAGE
echo "" >>$EMAILMESSAGE
echo "Current File Size: $FILESIZE bytes" >>$EMAILMESSAGE

# Send the Mail
/bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" < $EMAILMESSAGE
```

Comment: Please see the canonical [**Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?**](http://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a similar problem, because CRON can be quite finicky. My best guess would be that you need to add the path to the aws command, for instance:

```
/usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp /PATH/TO/SCRIPT/email-backup.mbox s3://XXXXXXXXXX/email-backup.mbox
```

Good Luck!

Comment: This did it, thanks! I was so preoccupied with paths to scripts I hadn't even considered paths to commands. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Excellent. Not a problem.