# cron ignores changes to /etc/crontab

Tags: cron

I'm seeing strange cron behavior which I'm not sure how to debug and fix.

It ignores changes to `/etc/crontab` until restarted, e.g. I edit `/etc/crontab` adding

`* * * * * root echo 'weee' > /tmp/stupidcron`

to it.
Then:

`root@linux-plba:~# sleep 270 && ls /tmp/stupidcron
ls: cannot access /tmp/stupidcron: No such file or directory`

Anything added with `crontab` utility works.

If I restart cron, the change is picked up, but any latter changes are not until the next restart.

I have root mail redirected to my inbox, and there's nothing of interest there. I also don't see anything in syslog.

Closest thing to this I've found is this old thread in FreeBSD mailing list:

http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2010-September/221179.html

The cron is Vixie cron 4.1-194.209.1 x86-64

Probably, someone have seen such behavior or knows how to further debug/fix it?

P.S. I did read the community wiki on it: [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it) and I believe this case is not covered there.

Comment: Which OS/Distro are you using ?

Comment: It's SLES 11.3, but it's sort of a lab machine and it's not eligible for tech support

Comment: Maybe try tracing the `cron` process, and see if it's calling `stat()` on `/etc/crontab` every minute like it should. Perhaps it's getting an error for some reason.

Comment: `strace -q -estat` says it does

Comment: The curious thing is `read` doesn't follow (unlike when I edit user's crontab)

Comment: I know one bug with cron in SLES: If you use a symbolic link to your crontab file (like those `cron.daily` files), and you change the crontab file, cron does not realize and still executes the old command. That also seems to indicate that cron actually caches the commands to execute.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it seems like this question has no actual answer.

My colleague decided to downgrade cron and see what happens, and it worked just fine.

So he looked through spec files in SRPMs for older and newer versions and it seems to be one of patches breaking cron:

`* Wed Aug  6 2014 tchvatal@suse.com
- Fix cron man page being ambiguous bnc#853010:
  * bnc#853010-manpage-ambiguous.patch
- Fix wrong mtime when reruning cron scripts bnc#879734:
  * bnc#879734-directory-mtime.patch`

Since the trace shows cron *does* stat the file and the struct it gets *is* correct, it's the cron issue, not something misconfigured/permissions problem etc.

Answer (score -2):

When you use crontab -e (the standard way of adding cron jobs) you may have noticed that you are editing a **temporary text file**. After you exit the crontabs are **installed** automatically.Crontab will create one file for each user in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`. And the cron daemon of course looks for `/etc/crontab` too.

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/crontab.ZRmGzQ/crontab installed on Mon May 12 07:50:40 2014)
```

This is the header of one user file in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`. It implies that editing the file will not do the job. Also `/tmp/crontab.ZRmGzQ/crontab` denotes the temporary file used by crontab -e at the last update.

```
sysadmin@omg:~$ crontab -l > tmp-cron.txt
sysadmin@omg:~$ echo '*/1 * * * * echo "APOEL ULTRAS" >> /tmp/stupidcron' >> tmp-cron.txt
sysadmin@omg:~$ crontab tmp-cron.txt
sysadmin@omg:~$ sleep 150 && cat /tmp/stupidcron
APOEL ULTRAS
APOEL ULTRAS
```

Here I am exporting my current crontabs to a temporary file tmp-cron.txt, adding a crontab and installing the file again. Works fine.

So basically the crontab in your case is not working because it has not been **installed**.

Just **be careful** when you install a new text file you overwrite the old. Backup your files before playing around.

Comment: It's true, but, from `man cron`: `Additionally,  cron  checks  each  minute  to  see  if its spool directory's modtime (or the modtime on /etc/crontab) has changed, and if it has, cron will then examine the modtime on all crontabs and reload those  which  have  changed. Thus cron  need not be restarted whenever a crontab file is modified. Note that the Crontab(1) command updates the modtime of the spool directory whenever it changes a crontab.` mtime of /etc/crontab does change when I edit it.

Comment: I think this is complete rubbish. On all the systems I have to hand, vixie-cron checks the user crontabs and the system crontabs every minute (the man page even says this) for changes.

Comment: Furthermore, the `crontab` command can only be used with user-specific crontabs. There's nothing analogous for `/etc/crontab`, you have to edit it directly, and that's specifically what the question is about.

Comment: Actually now that I revise this, it is complete rubbish indeed. I thought I replicated the problem, apparently I didn't.