# Cron not launching python script

Tags: linux, bash, cron

Python script is not being run, all other functions are running and stand alone script runs but combined... nada.
Initially it was `*/30 * * * * screen python ~/db_preset.py`
(Yes there was new line after)

Then I packed the script into bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep db_preset.py ; then
        :
else
        date >> ~/cron_log.log
        screen python /home/account/db_preset.py     
fi
```

and invoked it with 
`*/30 * * * * bash ~/scripts.sh`

Date gets logged, so it gets to that part but script is never launched

When I try simple cron like `*/2 * * * * date >> ~/cron_log.log`, works just fine

### Edit

I tried changing python path to `/usr/local/bin/python2.7 /home/account/db_preset.py; touch ~/a_command_has_run`

File gets created, so line is run afterall
Code is also good when run manually

Comment: is `~` a "sh" feature?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](http://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)

Comment: ~ means from home path, i played around with full path too. No change

Comment: @JennyD I looked an multitude of articles on this topic, including that. No luck

Comment: Why are you trying to run your script in a `screen`? This is almost certainly unnecessary.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly your problematic use of `screen`.  What is the purpose you are trying to accomplish with that?  Have you tried it without using `screen` anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely a pathing issue.

do: which python

It's likely to be at /usr/bin/python.

Then change your script to call the full path, ie: /usr/bin/python /home/account/db_preset.py

Comment: Come to think of it you could end up having the same issue with screen and have to call it with /usr/bin/screen as well.

Comment: i tried full path to python2.7... stil nada

Comment: Seems to be working now, although there was no immediate correct feedback from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Error messages from commands started through cron are sent by mail. If you look in the mail spool, you should be finding this error message: `Must be connected to a terminal.`

This is because you are trying to start the `screen` attached, which requires a terminal, and jobs run through `cron` have no terminal.

Starting new `screen` sessions from `cron` sounds dubious. You should probably just leave out the `screen` part. If you absolutely must start `screen` without a terminal, then start it detached. For example:

```
screen -dmS somename python ~/db_preset.py
```

Comment: i tried similar without screen before, still nothing