# Mail spam by root and smmsp

Tags: email, postfix

Whenever I go to the mail queue log in the ISPConfig monitor section, I see approx. 300 hundred requests like the following:

```
482BDFEC0187 712 Thu Oct 9 09:39:01 smmsp@server.example.com
(connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused)
root@server.example.com
```

Why are they here? It's either the `root` or `smmsp` user. Does this mean that my server is being attacked by spammers?

EDIT: I've already cleared the mail queue a day ago.

EDIT2: Here is an excerpt from the mail logs:

```
Oct 9 16:29:33 402283 postfix/error[4513]: 1EC3B6EC0105: to=<root@server.example.com/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused)
Oct 9 16:29:33 402283 postfix/error[4512]: 7A9166EC0135: to=<root@server.example.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=none, delay=118172, delays=118172/0.05/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused)
Oct 9 16:29:33 402283 postfix/error[4513]: 707A26EC00D7: to=<root@server.example.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=none, delay=151772, delays=151772/0.05/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused)
Oct 9 16:29:33 402283 postfix/error[4512]: 75D966EC009D: to=<root@server.example.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=none, delay=168572, delays=168572/0.05/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused)
Oct 9 16:30:01 402283 dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (disconnected before greeting, waited 0 secs): user=<>, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured, session=<Nz72bf0EyAB/AAAB>
Oct 9 16:30:01 402283 postfix/smtpd[4559]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
```

An excerpt of one email header from the mail queue:

```
named_attribute: rewrite_context=local
sender_fullname: CronDaemon
sender: root@server.example.com
original_recipient: root
recipient: root@server.example.com
```

Comment: Also, what should I pay attention to while configuring the mail server daemon?

Comment: This isn't spam. This is your cron daemon sending the output from its jobs, like cron normally does. If you want those mails, you should set your mail server daemon up so that it actually sends them to some useable mailbox. If not, you should fix your cron jobs so that they create logs instead of mails - see http://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

Comment: What you  should pay attention to: not making it an open relay... You appear to be using postfix; there's a lot of info at http://postfix.org including advice on how to set it up properly.

Comment: @Jenny Are you referring to this document? http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html

Comment: Is this tool reliable? http://mxtoolbox.com/diagnostic.aspx
I've tested my server and it appears to 'green' - not an open relay.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: If you hover over the down arrow, it will show you the main reason for downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most systems are configured to send mails of system events like the output of Cron tasks or failed sudo attempts to itself. These are sent mostly to the root user. If you are interested in these mails you should set up a catch all address for these mails.

Comment: It seems that I cannot send nor receive any mail at the moment (hence the 'Connection refused' errors). I suppose the server tries sending the emails again and again over periods of time?

Comment: Yes it does. The queue is regularly resent. But I think after x attempts it discards them.