# %CPU at 99% when cronjob runs php script every minute

Tags: linux, php, email, cron, cpu-usage

I am using a debian server and for some reason when I run this php script using crontab every minute it says that I am using 99% of the %CPU with the php command (in the cronjob the command is php) and the emails will not send. Eventually it says I am out of memory in the tmp folder. The weird part is that for about 10 minutes the cronjob worked perfectly; it sent me the emails every minute and the CPU usage was very low which was good. After that 10 minutes though, the CPU percentage spiked to about 99% again and the emails stopped sending.

If I manually send this email using the command: "php mail1.php", I receive the email with all the contents and there are no problems. With cronjob sending them, I can't even receive 1 anymore. If anyone has any idea why please let me know. Thanks

*UPDATE*: the server was being finicky so I deleted and retyped the same code over again, as well as deleting and recreating the same cronjob and it works properly.

Comment: For debugging cron see [this Q&A](http://serverfault.com/q/449651)

Comment: Check your cron PATH & ENV mate.

Answer (score -1):

you may have had some white-space in your code that was causing the server to hang. could also be a bad cron path. check your cron logs to see what is causing the server load.

Comment: This might be better as a comment

Comment: Not even a comment, in this case: Look at the question: the OP resolved it - there was a general server issue, and they restarted the job. Nothing to do with white-space or bad path (since the command originally worked).