# Certbot post-renewal/post-deploy hook in cron job

Tags: dovecot, lets-encrypt, certbot

On a mail server I need to reload Dovecot after Certbot renews my Let's Encrypt certificates. According to the [Certbot documentation](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html) a `--deploy-hook` can be used:

> Command to be run in a shell once for each issued certificate.

I found the cron job that was created automatically at `/etc/cron.d/certbot`, and with the help of  of certbot and [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/790772/cron-job-for-lets-encrypt-renewal) I figured I would use:

```
0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(43200))' && certbot -q renew --deploy-hook "service dovecot reload"
```

The problem is, Docecot does not appear to restart. Certificate renewal *is* still successful. **My question:** How to make sure Dovecot is reloaded after certificate renewal?

Addition information:
Server runs on **Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS** with **Certbot 0.31.0**.

Comment: I would expect a full path name for "service" in your deploy-hook, i.e., "/usr/sbin/service dovecot reload".

Comment: @OleWolf, you may be right, I will try your suggestion!

Comment: @OleWolf, it did not work unfortunately.

Comment: Does using the `systemctl` command change anything??

Comment: And also, what if you change `reload` to `restart`? try `--deploy-hook "systemctl restart dovecot"`

Answer (score 2):

Due to a lack of a comprehensive answer, I want to add the solution I went with after stumbling over this thread.

According to [readthedocs.io](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html):

> When Certbot detects that a certificate is due for renewal, --pre-hook
> and --post-hook hooks run before and after each attempt to renew it.
> If you want your hook to run only after a successful renewal, use
> --deploy-hook in a command like this.
>
> certbot renew --deploy-hook /path/to/deploy-hook-script

Derived from that, the "--deploy-hook" parameter expects a path to a script. I did not test if a quoted command would work as well, but it is my first guess that this is why your attempt failed.

> You can also specify hooks by placing files in subdirectories of
> Certbot’s configuration directory. Assuming your configuration
> directory is /etc/letsencrypt, any executable files found in
> /etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/pre,
> /etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/deploy, and
> /etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/post will be run as pre, deploy, and
> post hooks respectively when any certificate is renewed with the renew
> subcommand.

This is how I did it. I simply created a shell script in /etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/deploy, called it e.g. 00-do-stuff.sh and made it executable (`sudo chmod +x path/to/file`)

Please let me and everybody know if this works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Would --post-hook instead of --deploy-hook work ?
If so, deploy-hook will also work, but only in case of actual renewal.
maybe try this syntax as well :--deploy-hook="restart app..."