# Cannot add cron task

Tags: ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-20.04, custom-errors

I'm trying to add cron task to renew my certbot certificates everytime they are going to expire, but I can't seem to be able to do that.
I used this command: `crontab -e 0 12 * * * /usr/bin/certbot renew -quiet`

```
crontab: invalid option -- 'q'
crontab: usage error: unrecognized option
usage:  crontab [-u user] file
        crontab [ -u user ] [ -i ] { -e | -l | -r }
                (default operation is replace, per 1003.2)
        -e      (edit user's crontab)
        -l      (list user's crontab)
        -r      (delete user's crontab)
        -i      (prompt before deleting user's crontab)
```

Also tried this: `rontab -e 0 12 * * * /usr/bin/certbot renew --quiet`
And got:

```
crontab: invalid option -- '-'
crontab: usage error: unrecognized option
usage:  crontab [-u user] file
        crontab [ -u user ] [ -i ] { -e | -l | -r }
                (default operation is replace, per 1003.2)
        -e      (edit user's crontab)
        -l      (list user's crontab)
        -r      (delete user's crontab)
        -i      (prompt before deleting user's crontab)
```

This: `crontab -e 0 12 * * * /usr/bin/certbot renew -q`

```
crontab: invalid option -- 'q'
crontab: usage error: unrecognized option
usage:  crontab [-u user] file
        crontab [ -u user ] [ -i ] { -e | -l | -r }
                (default operation is replace, per 1003.2)
        -e      (edit user's crontab)
        -l      (list user's crontab)
        -r      (delete user's crontab)
        -i      (prompt before deleting user's crontab)
```

This: `crontab -e 0 12 * * * -q /usr/bin/certbot renew`

```
crontab: invalid option -- 'q'
crontab: usage error: unrecognized option
usage:  crontab [-u user] file
        crontab [ -u user ] [ -i ] { -e | -l | -r }
                (default operation is replace, per 1003.2)
        -e      (edit user's crontab)
        -l      (list user's crontab)
        -r      (delete user's crontab)
        -i      (prompt before deleting user's crontab)
```

This: `crontab -e 0 12 * * * --quiet /usr/bin/certbot renew`

```
crontab: invalid option -- '-'
crontab: usage error: unrecognized option
usage:  crontab [-u user] file
        crontab [ -u user ] [ -i ] { -e | -l | -r }
                (default operation is replace, per 1003.2)
        -e      (edit user's crontab)
        -l      (list user's crontab)
        -r      (delete user's crontab)
        -i      (prompt before deleting user's crontab)
```

This:  `crontab -e 0 12 * * *  /usr/bin/certbot renew`

```
crontab: usage error: no arguments permitted after this option
usage:  crontab [-u user] file
        crontab [ -u user ] [ -i ] { -e | -l | -r }
                (default operation is replace, per 1003.2)
        -e      (edit user's crontab)
        -l      (list user's crontab)
        -r      (delete user's crontab)
        -i      (prompt before deleting user's crontab)
```

I also tried `crontab -e 43 6 * * * certbot renew --post-hook "systemctl reload nginx"` from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/790776/977798), but it threw:

```
crontab: invalid option -- '-'
crontab: usage error: unrecognized option
usage:  crontab [-u user] file
        crontab [ -u user ] [ -i ] { -e | -l | -r }
                (default operation is replace, per 1003.2)
        -e      (edit user's crontab)
        -l      (list user's crontab)
        -r      (delete user's crontab)
        -i      (prompt before deleting user's crontab)
```

I don't know what else can I do. I use Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to just run `crontab -e` and then hit `Enter`.

**Then** your crontab will appear in the editor that is configured in your environment.

In the editor, you can **then** add the line to the crontab that you want to add:

```
0 12 * * * /usr/bin/certbot renew -quiet
```

The problem is your trying to do two steps in one.