# Why did my cron job run this month?

Tags: cron

Today is November 1st 2016 or in (unambiguous) numerals, 2016-11-01.

I have a user cron job set up like this:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
33  3   1  */2  *    /home/user/...
```

It is supposed to run every other month on the first of the month at 3:33am, no matter what day of week that is, but for some reason it was run today, even though 11 is not divisible by 2.

Can someone explain me this? Is my assumption of divisibility by 2 wrong?

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I am running `cron` version "3.0pl1-127+deb8u1" on a Debian 8.6 "Jessie" machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](http://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)

Comment: So you're talking about the 11th day of the 2016th month of the year 1 then. :)  (The most common date order in America is month-day-year.)

Comment: @chicks check the edit history of this question, I originally used the format you mentioned ;-)

Comment: @chicks you mean month/day/year?

Comment: @immibis No. ... comfreak: lol

Comment: I assumed ISO8601 from the year-first ordering

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The `/` is not an arithmetic expression, instead it describes "step values" over the *allowed* range of values. So, since months always start with `1` instead of `0`, `/2` would mean "take every other value", resulting in (1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11).

This is also decribed in the manual page, although this is not terrible clear and easy to understand:

> Step values can be used in conjunction with ranges.  Following a range with "<number>" specifies skips of the number’s value through the range.  For
>          example,  "0-23/2"  can  be  used  in  the  hours  field  to  specify  command  execution  every  other  hour (the alternative in the V7 standard is
>          "0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22").  Steps are also permitted after an asterisk, so if you want to say "every two hours", just use "*/2".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just realized this myself after reading the man page again and working this through in my head. I was usually only working with shorter term cron jobs where the numbers start with 0 and my assumption actually made sense in a way.

Comment: I just mused why this question isn't asked more often and came to the same conclusion: Because few people run jobs with anything then a "*" in the month field.

Comment: One question, what would happen if the number does not divide, e.g. `*/5`? Would it be 1,6,11,1,6... or would it be 1,6,11,4,9...? I assumed that "over the allowed range of values" means that it has no memory, but now I was not being so sure about that.

Comment: @MariusSiuram: The first variant. Again, this is not an arithmetic operation. `crond` just takes the list of possible values, applies the step selector once and then use these results repeatedly.

Answer (score 4):

Today is the first day in November.

*/2 means that your cronjob will execute every other month as you say.

So next month (December) the cronjob will not be executed, but the month (January) after it will be.

The month before this month (October) the cronjob was not executed. But in September it was.

Comment: So you reckon that `*/2` in the month field is equivalent to `1-11/2`, rather than `2-12/2`.  I'm not saying you're wrong, but can you produce any supporting documentation?

Comment: @MadHatter Sven did explain it well.

Comment: I agree, and best of all he quoted authoritative sources.

Comment: Just pointing out, September precedes October, and not August ;-)