# Cronjob unable to restart apache in CentOS 6

Tags: centos6, cron, service, plesk

I'm using Plesk 12 + CentOS 6.

I ssh into `root` account and use `crontab -e` to create the following entry:

`* * * * * service httpd restart`

I expect it to restart apache every minute (just to test/debug it's working)

I checked the apache status using `service httpd status` and the PID is always the same, and apache is not restarting.

I verified `/var/log/cron` that the command is being executed.

`Feb  7 16:11:01 srv104 CROND[15620]: (root) CMD (service httpd restart)`

However, all other entries in the `crontab` are correctly executing.

If I execute the command `service httpd restart` manually in shell terminal, apache is restarting correctly with a new updated PID.

Is there any preventive measure in place such that `service` can't be executed in `root cronjob`?

---

[Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it) has some useful tips, but does not address my specific situation mentioned in the original question above.

**Working Solution:**

If I specify the full path to the `/sbin/service`, eg. `/sbin/service httpd restart` in the cronjob, as mentioned in the accepted answer, it does work.

Not sure if it's operating system version related, but simply with the `PATH` in place in `/etc/crontab/` does not help in my situation.

Comment: Try to set PATH variable in your  crontab properly. By default, it may look for executables into /bin or /usr/bin directories only. As 'service' script/tool is in /sbin directory it may be not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your command with `/sbin/service httpd restart`.

Or as pointed out in the comments: setting a PATH in `/etc/crontab`, including `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` should do.

Comment: My current `/etc/crontab` already has this entry: `PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` and it failed to restart apache with just `service httpd restart` in cronjob entry.  However, if I specify the full path as you mentioned, `/sbin/service httpd restart`, it does work.