# Webmin gives RPC error when trying to execute a scheduled Cron Job

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, webmin

When trying to run a cron job I created via webmin I get this error:

```
Running letsencrypt renew on selected servers ..
Failed to run on ... (this server) : RPC error :
```

I just noticed this today but i think this error is there for maybe 2 or 3 days.

I am running webmin on Apache and Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](http://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)

Answer (score 0):

A simple `sudo reboot` did the job after all..