# @reboot and all 23hours with a single crontab entry

Tags: cron

I couldn't find any documentation/examples regarding this usage syntax, are we allowed to use `@reboot` and 23 hours daily in a single command?

I have this cron job schedule to delete my tomcat logs every day 23 hours, now I want this same script need to be run after reboot too. Any suggestions?

```
0 23 * * * find /tomcat/logs/*.log -mtime +1 -delete
```

**EDIT:**

I am not asking about why my cron tab is not working (or) how to work with cron tab, my question is more about can we have command with @reboot as well as hours in single command?

Comment: What's wrong with adding another line and replacing 0 23 * * * with @reboot?

Comment: @yoonix nothing wrong, I thought one line will solve both purposes if that syntax is supported, otherwise I would end up with 2 lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)

Comment: Keep it simple. Two lines is probably easier to maintain than some exotic syntax hackery few would be familiar with.

Comment: @DanielWidrick Thanks! seems that is what I might end up doing.