# cron won't execute second part of command

Tags: linux, cron, ubuntu-16.04

After **carefully** reviewing the [general "cron" answer](https://serverfault.com/q/449651/269290), I am still stuck.
My crontab reads:

> ```
> # m h  dom mon dow   command
> */5 * * * * /usr/bin/pkill -f process.py && /usr/bin/python /path/to/process.py > /path/to/process.log 2>&1
> ```

I want `process.py` to be restarted every 5 minutes.
The `pkill` parts works as expected and `process.py` is killed every 5 minutes.
**However**, the second part of my cron task (restarting `process.py`) does not happen!
- The log file `/path/to/process.log` does not contain any error, in fact it is not changed.
- running the command outside cron works.
- looking at `/var/log/syslog` only shows cron executing the command, but no output/errors seem to be logged anywhere
- I tried both `;` and `&&` between the two commands. No good.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: @anx yes. I would like to **restart** `process.py` every 5 minutes.

Comment: Generally I find that for any logic more complex than running a single command it is better to write a (simple) shell script and have cron execute that.

Comment: Check the permissions on '/path/to/process.log'  It sounds like the cron user is not the same one you are testing with - likely the user you test with (root?) owns the log file and the cron process can't write to it.

Comment: @BrandonXavier the log file has the same owner as the crontab. the log has appropriate write permissions.

Comment: @HBruijn I followed your advice. a script indeed did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible the `pkill` is killing the cron process to trigger the new instance of `process.py` because the regex finds both the running `process.py` and the cron process which is about to start it?

Comment: oh god please no! if `pkill` is that thorough - what can I do?!

Comment: When your `process.py` starts, write the pid somewhere, and then have a proper cleanup process which reads the pid and stops only that process (assuming my solution is correct, which is far from proven).

Comment: Looking at [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/506295/350717) it does not seems like `pkill` is that thorough...

Comment: It's not about thoroughness, it's about what processes exist at the point that the `pkill` runs and which ones match the regexp.  Try using `-c` and logging the output see if it returns more than 1.