# Run two cron jobs in sync

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-16.04, scheduled-task

I would like to run cron job A every 3 minutes, and cron job B every 5 minutes. But I would like job A to always run 3 minutes before job B.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: ?? - job A0 run at 0h12, job B0 would run at 0h15, but then job A1 would run also.

Comment: Is this a trick question?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I wish I had to the time for that...

Comment: @Archemar, right, hence the need to sync them.

Comment: I asked a more specific question, but my challenge is to make job A run before job B. i can't put the two together because B needs to finish in less than 30 seconds, and A takes a little over a min to finish

Comment: what about `jobA ; jobB` with a semicolon ?

Comment: You might want to take look at some of the mechanism's I use to deal with [irregular cron schedules](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it/815541#815541) - let both A & B use the same `flock` and you prevent running  the batches concurrently. Record the last successful run of A and don't start B until the minimum interval has passed.