# Cron job running a Django Python command through a virtual environment not working

Tags: cron, python, django, environment-variables

I have a crontab file supposedly executing a Django command after loading the project virtual environment:

```
*/1 * * * * source /home/virtualenvs/mydjangoproject-venv/bin/activate && python /home/www/production/mydjangoproject/manage.py mydjangocommand
```

...but it does absolutely nothing. The cron log outputs no particular problem:

```
Mar 13 19:51:01 110 CRON[23807]: (root) CMD (source /home/virtualenvs/mydjangoproject-venv/bin/activate && python /home/www/production/mydjangoproject/manage.py mydjangocommand)
```

Needless to say, the command itself works perfectly when copy-pasted in the shell.

I know it is related to the environment variables of my crontab, but I'm very uneducated regarding this matter, and I have no idea what to do especially when it is run under a python virtual env. Should it use my user environment variables? The ones from the virtualenv? How to implement that? Thanks!

NB: In case it helps, I have the following output of my crontab environment variables (when exporting "env" to a file through the crontab):

```
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
PWD=/root
```

And the following environment variables under the project virtual environment:

```
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
SSH_CLIENT=x.x.x.x 53007 22
OLDPWD=/root/production/mydjangoproject
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
USER=root
VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/virtualenvs/mydjangoproject-venv
MAIL=/var/mail/root
PATH=/home/virtualenvs/mydjangoproject-
venv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/root
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
PS1=(mydjangoproject-venv)${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@$(hostname -f):\w\$ 
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
LS_OPTIONS=--color=auto --group-directories-first
LOGNAME=root
SSH_CONNECTION=x.x.x.x 53007 x.x.x.x 22
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UT
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)

Comment: @AndrewSchulman This situation is not covered at all in that question. A somewhat embarrassing oversight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to solve this:

First, it doesn't work because `/bin/sh` is the shell cron uses to run commands, but `/bin/sh` doesn't support `source`. So the quick fix is to set `SHELL=/bin/bash` in the crontab.

Or...

Second, it's not necessary to `source virtualenv/bin/activate` anyway. You can just call the virtualenv python directly.

```
* * * * * cd /home/www/production/mydjangoproject; /home/virtualenvs/mydjangoproject-venv/bin/python manage.py mydjangocommand
```

These were taken from [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3287038/1068283), the answers to which may contain other ideas for people in similar but not quite the same circumstances.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have tried both your solutions, and both work! So it wasn't a problem exactly related to environment variables.