# How to setup a cron job every random weekday?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, bash, cron

As the question is fairly self-explanatory, I would like to know how to set a cronjob to execute any random weekday without using any external script.

EDIT: In case people have not understood this question, We have 5 weekdays, viz., Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday. I have a server running 24/7. I want to set a cron that will run on `any 1 weekday` per week.

Note: I highly doubt this is a duplicate question, as this question is not pertaining to `daily`/`weekly`/`monthly` cronjobs.

Comment: Computers are quite bad at true randomness, *"execute any random weekday"* is that  *"run **at least** once a week"* or *"run  **exactly** once a week" or it is also okay if it will at times  *"run  **on all 5 workdays** in a single a week", skip a week, to run twice the next... As I mentioned in the [linked duplicate](https://serverfault.com/a/815541/376810) *"Cron is all things considered a very basic scheduler and the syntax does not easily allow an administrator to formulate slightly more uncommon schedule"* - One option is to start a batch with `sleep $RANDOM` statement to delay execution

Comment: Let it run daily, but check for the existence of a file first (which you create after the first complete, successful run).

Comment: Cron has no support for that. You can do it by wrapping the script. The wrapper should run the script with 20% probability on Monday, with 25% probability on Tuesday, with 33% on Wednesday, and so on. It should also disable running if it has already run on this week. It is a trivial unix script. Note, doing things *randomly* is typically a bad idea, you need to make your systems so deterministic as you only can!

Comment: Btw, also I disagree that your question would be a dupe. However I would suggest you to think twice, if you really needs a random behavior. If it doesn't work, how will you debug it? If you need to think on, what caused what a system, the complexity of a deterministic system grows linearly with its size, a non-deterministic grows exponentially. Of course I can imagine an enough strong reason for this cron, but I think it is much more likely, that you only want to fix/avoid something with it. Do that on a deterministic way!

Comment: Btw, such interesting problems having more connection to shellscripting than to professional system administration, may have a better welcome on the https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 3):

Would something like this work for you? It selects a random day from a bash array `days` (note the SHELL prefix) and then writes a cronjob (`random_runner`) under `/etc/cron.d` to run the script `/home/foobar/myscript`.

You could place this in `/etc/cron.d/random_generator` and generate a new "runner" every day.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
27 8 * * * root  days=(Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun); rd="$(( RANDOM \% 7 ))"; day="${days[$rd]}"; echo "45 15 * * $day root /home/foobar/myscript" > /etc/cron.d/random_runner
```