# Cron task doesn't run

Tags: ubuntu, bash, cron

I have this crontab task:

```
$ sudo crontab -l  -u root
0 22 * * * certbot renew --cert-name app.my_website123.net --pre-hook "systemctl nginx stop" --post-hook "systemctl nginx start" >> /home/my_user/cron_log1.log 2>&1
```

**certbot renew** requires root.

The log file still doesn't exist, after several days, which implies that the task doesn't get executed. **Why is that?**

Comment: ***”The last command in my crontab doesn't run”***

*Cron generally requires that commands are terminated with a new line. Edit your crontab; go to the end of the line which contains the last command and insert a new line (press enter).* - in addition to using an absolute path as Seamus remarked

Comment: @HBruijn I know

Answer (score 5):

Your `crontab` entry looks fine, with one possible exception: `certbot` should probably have a full path specification. For example:

```sh
0 22 * * * /path/to/certbot .....
```

If that doesn't resolve the issue, we'll need more information. I suspect the issue is the environment, but we'll need to ask `cron` what environment has been created for the `root` user. We can phrase our question as follows:

- Create a shell script in your home directory (`~/`) as follows (or with the editor of your choice):

```
$ nano ~/envtst.sh
```

- Enter the following in the editor, after adjusting for your system/user:

```sh
#!/bin/sh 
/bin/echo "env report follows for user "$USER >> /home/you/envtst.sh.out 
/usr/bin/env >> /home/you/envtst.sh.out 
/bin/echo "env report for user "$USER" concluded" >> /home/you/envtst.sh.out
/bin/echo " " >> /home/you/envtst.sh.out
```

- Save the file, exit the editor and set file permissions as executable.

```sh
$ chmod a+rx ~/envtst.sh
```

- Run the script you just created, and review the output in `/home/you/envtst.sh.out`. This output will show your current environment as the `$USER` you're logged in as:

```sh
$ ./envtst.sh $$ cat /home/you/envtst.sh.out
```

- Open your `crontab` for editing:

```sh
$ crontab -e -u root
```

- Enter the following line at the bottom of your `crontab`:

```sh
* * * * *  /home/you/envtst.sh >> /home/you/envtst.sh.err 2>&1
```

The output file `/home/you/envtst.sh.out` will contain a listing of the `environment` for the "root cron user". Once you know that, adjust your `crontab` entry for `certbot` accordingly. Post the output here if questions remain.