# Ubuntu Server Cron Jobs not running

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, escaping

iam about to blow up: i cant figure out why my jobs in the crontab -e file of any user are not running. None of them do so the "last cron job is not running" problem is not aplicable. Also i checked [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it) thread and couldn't find any mistakes. I even escaped my percent signs.

Here's my crontab -e file when running under the root user:

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# Minute Stunde TagIMonat Monat TagIWoche Kommando
# m h  dom mon dow   command
50 3 * */2 * /usr/bin/openssl pkcs12 -export -out /home/user/export.pfx -inkey /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/chain.pem -password pass: blabla > /var/log/cron.log
51 3 * */2 * /usr/bin/sshpass -p xxx scp /home/user/export.pfx root@255.255.255.255:/path/to/file/> /var/log/cron.log
0 0 */5 * * /usr/bin/rsync -avx /var/www/nextcloud/apps /nextcloud/backup/path/nextcloud-apps_`date +"\%Y\%m\%d"`/ > /var/log/cron.log
0 0 */5 * * /usr/bin/rsync -avx /var/www/nextcloud/config/config.php /nextcloud/backup/path/nextcloud-config_`date +"\%Y\%m\%d"`/ > /var/log/cron.log
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump --single-transaction -h localhost -u user -pPassword db > /nextcloud/backup/path/nextcloud-sqlbkp_`date + "\%Y\%m\%d"`.sql > /var/log/cron.log
```

Maybe someone can help me with my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh my :)

At first you should not paste such long and complex oneliners into cron directly. Instead, create bash scripts for all these commands.

i.e. you can replace:

```
0 0 */5 * * /usr/bin/rsync -avx /var/www/nextcloud/apps /nextcloud/backup/path/nextcloud-apps_`date +"\%Y\%m\%d"`/ > /var/log/cron.log
0 0 */5 * * /usr/bin/rsync -avx /var/www/nextcloud/config/config.php /nextcloud/backup/path/nextcloud-config_`date +"\%Y\%m\%d"`/ > /var/log/cron.log
```

with

```
0 0 */5 * * /root/bin/rsync_cronjobs.sh > /var/log/cron.log
```

and move your commands into bash script, i.e. `/root/bin/rsync_cronjobs.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`

/usr/bin/rsync -avx /var/www/nextcloud/apps /nextcloud/backup/path/nextcloud-apps_${DATE}/
/usr/bin/rsync -avx /var/www/nextcloud/config/config.php /nextcloud/backup/path/nextcloud-config_${DATE}`/
```

looks cleaner right?

Also, make sure you understand how often these cronjobs are running. You can examine them using [cronwtf](https://cronwtf.com/). For safety never paste anything private (like passwords) into such tools.