# Cron Job Issue - Centos 7 ( Centos Webpanel)

Tags: centos7, cron, incrontab

The following cronjob don´t work in my server and I don´t understand the reason 
Cron:

```
`curl https://app.codexbot.co/cron_job/background_scanning_update_subscriber_info/1-NmZTjQk1575844678nNCBzwb >/dev/null 2>&1`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)

Comment: In general you start debugging faulty cron jobs by ensuring you do not discard any error messages, so change the `>/dev/null 2>&1` to log to a file such /tmp/my-cron.log with `>> /tmp/my-cron.log 2>&1`

Comment: this is the log:

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0

Comment: https://prnt.sc/q8wx1z a screenshot

Comment: At first glance that seem to indicate that the cron job gets executed (otherwise there would be no output recorded at all) but the download stalls (the zero bytes received) which can have any number of reasons, from firewalls, the need to use a web proxy, to selinux and other access controls

Comment: I don´t have enough knowledge about that and what is the next step :( ( begginner user)