# mailx does not run using crontab

Tags: redhat, cron, mailx

I have a script which sends emails. It works perfectly when run manually but I doesn't work when run with crontab:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $HOME/myfolder/mailbody | /bin/mailx -v -s "mymail" -a file.txt xxx.yyy@zzz.com > $HOME/myfolder/script.log
```

When run with crontab, nothing is written in "$HOME/myfolder/script.log". I can't understand why with crontab the command to send the email is not run.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)

Comment: I'm 100% sure crontab works since, if I add a log line before mailx command, it gets written. The problem is that, with crontab, the line code to send the mail seems not to be executed. I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Which crontab file? Could it be $HOME is not set?

Comment: I edited crontab using "crontab -e" and I'm sure $HOME is set because I see it in the log if I add a log line before mailx command.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by specifying the **absolute path** to mailx attachment argument:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $HOME/myfolder/mailbody | /bin/mailx -v -s "mymail" -a /path/to/file.txt xxx.yyy@zzz.com > $HOME/myfolder/script.log
```