# Backing up a large database using mysqldump and CRON

Tags: mysqldump

I'm trying to backup a single MySql Database on my website using CRON but it's not working. Command is

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD --databases DATABASENAME | gzip > /home/MYSITE/forumbackup/backup.$(date +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S").sql.gz
```

There is no error message in log files or the default email account.  I know the location of mysqldump is correct as I checked with my hoster.  I'm assuming gzip can be called as is.

any advice?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: How did you determine that it's "not working"?

Comment: What is the user the cronjob is executing as?

Comment: There is no backup file in the directory specified, The user being used was used before I migrated hosts and was working previously with a PHP script.  It is a DB user with rights.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)

Comment: Note that among other the `%` percent sign usually has special meaning in cron tab files and may need extra escapes

Comment: I thought I had solved this. I escaped the % signs in the date statement \% instead of just %. The mysqdump file is created in the correct directory but is only 20kb and it should be about 545,000Kb

Comment: May be a password issue, db user account was created on new host, I have reset the password and will try again.

Comment: Tat all worked, problem resolved.