# crontab: using ${USER}

Tags: cron, environment-variables

I am writing some scripts that uses ${USER} to point to subsequent scripts. But when I run it from crontab, it errors out and the files are not found. I understand why.

I intend to share this with my colleagues and each time the colleague has to manually change the first line to his own username. How can I minimize this issue (not have a manual way to change that one line)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider No, it doesn't cover this situation.

Answer (score 2):

It's a typo. You should use `$USER`, not `${USER}`.

Cron parses these lines itself and does only simple variable substitution; it is not a shell.