# Crontab not running @reboot

Tags: ubuntu, cron, cron.daily

I have ubuntu server with crontab that is supposed to run `mkdocs` in `tmux` at reboot.
Worth noting is that I configure crontab by going into `crontab -e`.
Line is:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/tmux new-session -d -s "MKDOCS" "cd /root/mkdocs && mkdocs serve -a 192.168.0.10:8080"
```

However, nothing happens.

I have tried just `/usr/bin/tmux new-session -d -s "MKDOCS" "cd /root/mkdocs && mkdocs serve -a 192.168.0.10:8080"` and it runs fine.
What can be the reason? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)

Comment: As described in the linked Q&A fairly common are missing newlines on the last entry of a crontab file and relying on relative path names for commands that do not live in the very limited `$PATH` used by cron. - On a different note: most sysadmins prefer services that actually run as a service rather than in tmux/screen session.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider There is no mention of the reboot option on that page.

Comment: @Bob the path shouldn't be an issue, if you notice I am running commands with full path. ( example instead of Tmux I am running /usr/bin/tmux).
I know but this is a temporary solution and there are reasons I am doing it this way, however the corn doesn't seem to do anything  at reboot.

Comment: So, you did check that it works when you enter an actual time instead of @reboot?