# When I execute a script in crontab the output is in a different language

Tags: linux, cron, command-line-interface

I am executing a script in a crontab that writes a log, when I run it as root, the log is written in spanish.

But when I run it in the crontab, the output is in english.

Is there a way to run the crontab with the same configuration I do when I run it as root?

Comment: Set the proper `LC_*` variables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)

Comment: I can not identify my problem there... Could you please provide me an example? @GeraldSchneider

Comment: The problem is that the `LC_*` variables are unset. How to set them in cron is described in the linked question.

Comment: Not directly. I decided to write a concrete answer, but mention the general panacea answer and you originally posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possible solutions; you could write a wrapper script that sets the appropriate enviroment variables and then calls your original cron script. If you want the LANG - which is what I expect you need to set - to be the same for all scripts you just define it at the top of your crontab. This is explained in the answer [Gerald Schneider](https://serverfault.com/users/38644/gerald-schneider) linked [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it) but not explicitely for LC_* or LANG. Here's how to do it:

```
LANG=es_ES
*/15 */2 3 * * /opt/jobs/repeat-this.sh
```

Depending on what your script does you may need to set specifc LC_* values; or simply set LC_ALL=es_ES.

LC_CTYPE, LC_NUMERIC, LC_TIME, LC_COLLATE, LC_MONETARY, LC_MESSAGES, LC_PAPER, LC_NAME, LC_ADDRESS, LC_TELEPHONE, LC_MEASUREMENT, LC_IDENTIFICATION, LC_ALL