# zipping in crontab does not work

Tags: cron, zip

Im trying to zip my savegames (an push them to dropbox). However, even though zipping works fine it does not seem to work when I past the command into contab.

```
* * * * * cd /home/steam/.config/Epic/FactoryGame/Saved/SaveGames && zip -r Backup_$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M").zip /home/steam/.config/Epic/FactoryGame/Saved/SaveGames
```

For testing purposes I will make a zip every minute. Cron runs and all the pathes seem to work.

Edit: I am running Debian 10

Comment: Well, what you do with your savegames is off topic here. Until the question is closed you can take a look at our [very helpful canonical question `Why is my crontab not working and how can I troubleshoot it`](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it).

Comment: @phil just put the commands into an script, it should work