# Duplicity Macos crontab (python errors )

Tags: mac-osx, cron, python, duplicity

I am having errors while running duplicity in macOS (crontab)

The duplicity command is as follows (works in Command-line)

```
/usr/local/bin/duplicity /Users/myname/go file:///Volumes/EVO840\ -\ IMPORTANT/DuplicityGo/ --exclude '**/bin/***' --exclude '**/pkg'
```

When using `crontab -e` (with and without sudo),

```
* * * * * /Users/myname/bashscripts/duplicity.sh > /Users/myname/bashscripts/duplicity.log 2>&1
```

it returns following error

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/duplicity", line 87, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/local/bin/duplicity", line 72, in with_tempdir
    tempdir.default().cleanup()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/duplicity/0.8.23/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/duplicity/tempdir.py", line 69, in default
    _defaultInstance = TemporaryDirectory(temproot=config.temproot)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/duplicity/0.8.23/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/duplicity/tempdir.py", line 155, in __init__
    temproot = subprocess.check_output([u'getconf', u'DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR'])
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 505, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'getconf'

Attempt of list Nr. 1 failed. PermissionError: Operation not permitted
Attempt of list Nr. 3 failed. PermissionError: Operation not permitted
Attempt of list Nr. 4 failed. PermissionError: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: By default not every OSX application has "full disk access" permissions and `cron` doesn't have that either. See for example https://osxdaily.com/2020/04/27/fix-cron-permissions-macos-full-disk-access/

Comment: Thank you very much for quick answer. I tried adding cron, as well as duplicity to Full Disk Access, and unfortunately, error still exist for `No such file or directory: 'getconf'`

Comment: The second problem: https://serverfault.com/q/449651/37681

Comment: I figured out the problem was due to using external volumes. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

cron often has no or a limited PATH env var set only. set it on top of your crontab to the same value you use in your commandline and the error will likely vanish.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem arises from me using **Removable Volume** as destination for duplicity.

In order for my bash script to work (or even just running duplicity in crontab), I have to add /bin/bash to Full Disk Access (though, I think it's feels unsafe)