# Crontab query - won't execute program

Tags: cron

Noob question.

I have an executable file saved here:

```
/home/pi/auroramon-1.07/src/auroramon
```

When I enter `/home/pi/auroramon-1.07/src/auroramon` in the command line the program runs.

I created a crontab to execute the program at startup by doing the following:

```
crontab -e
```

and added:

```
@reboot /home/pi/auroramon-1.07/src/auroramon
```

on rebooting, the program doesn't start

When I run:

```
$ sudo systemctl status cron.service
```

I get:

```
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-09-16 16:24:59 BST; 4min 41s ago
       Docs: man:cron(8)
   Main PID: 351 (cron)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 3720)
        CPU: 260ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
             └─351 /usr/sbin/cron -f

Sep 16 16:24:59 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Regular background program processing daemon.
Sep 16 16:24:59 raspberrypi cron[351]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Sep 16 16:24:59 raspberrypi cron[351]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Sep 16 16:24:59 raspberrypi CRON[353]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user ajandco(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Sep 16 16:24:59 raspberrypi CRON[381]: (ajandco) CMD (/home/pi/auroramon-1.07/src/auroramon)
Sep 16 16:25:01 raspberrypi CRON[353]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user ajandco
```

which I think is telling me the cron service was running, it executed the necessary command to start the program then closed the cron session.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong / why the program won't start on reboot?

Comment: The duplicate will almost certainly answer your question. If it does not, it will help you gather information that you canedit into your question to help people help you.

Answer (score 0):

The `cron` is executed, but probably it need some environment variables, PATH, etc.
What you can do is to create shell script like this:

```
source /home/pi/.bash_profile
/home/pi/auroramon-1.07/src/auroramon
```

and change the `cron` record to point this shell script.

Comment: Almost everycront question can be closed as a dupe of https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

Comment: @user9517, true. Only `cron` about UNIX make the difference :)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Romeo, I had to go in another direction. Apparently cron @reboot can't be used for applications that require desktop GUI as these will attempt to start your programs too early in the boot process. I used sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart instead and put the path to the executable there.