# is my crontab syntax invalid?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

simple question:

`10 4 * * * rm -rf ~/code/rehlds/build/ && ~/code/rehlds/build.sh --compiler=gcc --jobs=4 > /dev/null 2>&1`

I checked an there is no /build folder which indicates that the build.sh did not execute.

`crontab -e`

`10 4 * * * rm -rf ~/code/rehlds/build/ && ~/code/rehlds/build.sh --compiler=gcc --jobs=4 > /dev/null 2>&1`

`pgrep cron 658 1232359`

so here I can see it was run
`sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog` 
`Dec  8 04:10:01 xxxx CRON[1190963]: (xxx) CMD (rm -rf ~/code/rehlds/build/ && ~/code/rehlds/build.sh --compiler=gcc --jobs=4 > /dev/null 2>&1)`

my job ran, but no compiling, that cronlog file is empty.

`CMD (./code/rehlds/build.sh --compiler=gcc --jobs=4 &> ./cronlog)`

Comment: Does the logs have any relevant errors?

Comment: With all output redirected to/dev/null there most probably are no logs.

Comment: Set output to log file, not `dev/null` and run again

Comment: `10 4 * * * rm -rf ~/code/rehlds/build/ && ~/code/rehlds/build.sh --compiler=gcc --jobs=4 > ~somelog` like this? will it create this `somelog` if not existing?

Comment: No, use something like: `>/full/path/log 2> /full/path/err` to generate log for STDOUT and for STDERR. And use absolute paths

Comment: not even this works for 5min `* * * * * touch ./testfile &> ./testlog
`

Comment: ok now i found out that if you are working with 2 bash sessions and save in nano, then the file is not written, only if you close it...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)

Comment: why does this log output not work? `somecmd > ~/rehldslog 2>&1`. in the logs i can see `(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
` and somecmd did not run

Answer (score 0):

1. if you work with 2 bash session, you must not only save the file with nano, but close it, only then is the crontab added.
2. when executing the build.sh I must first cd into that directory otherwise error:

`$ ./code/rehlds/build.sh --compiler=gcc --jobs=4 CMake Error: The source directory "/home/cs2" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt. Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI. make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

I found that out by manually executing this command

correct command:

`10 4 * * * cd ./code/rehlds && rm -rf ./build && ./build.sh --compiler=gcc --jobs=4 > /dev/null 2>&1`