# What is the best directory to place your cron jobs?

Tags: ubuntu, cron

We have a machine that executes cron jobs. We'd like to upload (via scp) cron job files to. Here is an example of a cron job file (test.cron):

```
* * * * * echo "test" > /tmp/test_cron
```

This runs if you do it using `crontab -e` then save, and then that ends up in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER`, we can't use this anymore (company policy).

If I place this file `test.cron` in the `/etc/cron.d` it doesn't run. Do I need to change this file syntax or put this file elsewhere so it's picked up by cron deamon and ran?

**Update:**

When I paste contents of the `test.cron` into `crontab -e` it gets executed. My crontab syntax seems to be valid.

**My question is**: Where do I need to put/drop/place `test.cron` file with the content above, so that it gets picked up by cron daemon?

**More context**: I don't know in advance at what interval the cron file command will need to be ran. None of these are probably a good place "cron.daily/   cron.hourly/  cron.monthly/ cron.weekly/" I could be wrong that's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)

Comment: hey @GeraldSchneider my crontab is working, but I am asking where should I drop the file in (which directory so that it gets picked up by cron). I ll edit question to provide more clarity

Comment: @Titi Did you read the suggested answer? Particularly how cron.d has an additional column for the username compared to the traditional user crontab

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist yes I did, I tried that and it worked. Is there any other way other than placing files in /etc/cron.d ? thanks

Comment: Regarding your statement: *"`/var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER`, we can't use this anymore (company policy)."* 

What is your actual policy?  What needs to be achieved there? Because opening up root SFTP access (needed to drop files into `/etc/cron.d` ) is hardly an improvement compared  to allowing a regular user to manage their own cronjobs IMHO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/etc/cron.d` is a feature of the crond that may have to be explicitly enabled.
It is enabled by default on Debian-based distros.
So `/etc/cron.d` is the right place when you are on a Debian derivative.

The cron manpage on Debian says:

> Files in [/etc/crond.d] must conform to the same naming convention as used by run-parts(8) : they must consist solely of upper- and lower-case letters, digits, underscores, and hyphens.  This means that they **cannot contain any dots**.

So you have to rename your `test.cron` to eg. `test_cron` and it should start to work.