# Crontab I have tried cronitor airplane nothing helps

Tags: cron, syslog

my crontabs do not run, sys log gives me this, Jan  6 08:30:02 joe-sbc-flt1 CRON[102851]: (joe) CMD (/home/joe/scripts/watchit.sh) I have no idea what it means or what is wrong, can anyone help?

Comment: The log shows cron launched `/home/joe/scripts/watchit.sh` as user `joe`. How is it not working?

Comment: I get no output where I expect it the watch it file is this, watch -n 60  ffmpeg -hide_banner -i https://www.nps.gov/webcams-yell/west_gate.jpg?   -f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 10 -segment_format mkv /home/joe/AA-wg/%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S.mkv. It runs if I put it in terminal, I am confused, run by itself I get a picture every minute

Comment: I know the ffmpeg segment part is wrong but it gives the desired output every minute, I'm working on that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)

Comment: No it does not, I have worked with the folks at Cronitor and Airplane also and so far no one has figured what I am most likely doing wrong.

Comment: Could it be your script doesn't work at all...

Comment: I was executing a watch command which clears the terminal before it executes and I think that was killing my expected output. I am now running the command without the watch command and it is working, thanks to you all for steering  me in the right direction