# Error when I execute crontab in linux

Tags: linux, cron, cron.daily

I'm executing a crontab where it call the script of python and the crontab are executing very well, but when I execute the crontab I need its will create other file in another directory, but that doesn't do what I want.

But when execute manually script those create the file that i Need

I want know if with linux can I something more or i have check the code of script

this is the crontab
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please test your case similar to the below config:(since you posted image, I was not able to copy your file name and your path). just replace yours instead and update the time as you want.

```
*/15 * * * * root /usr/bin/python3.9 /usr/local/scripts/domainadder.py > /dev/null 2>&1
```