# solaris 10 cron job won't run but will run fine from command line

Tags: cron, solaris

```
#!/bin/sh

 

#grab oldest file from queue

stuff=\`ls -1 /var/spool/lp/requests/localhost/ | /usr/bin/head -1\`

#pull printer name from lp requests (first line in file)

puff=\`cat $stuff | /usr/bin/head -1 | sed -e 's/-.*//' -e 's/$/ is having issues printing from /'\`

 

if [ "$(ls -A /var/spool/lp/requests/localhost/)" ]

then

        echo $puff | /usr/ucb/mail foo@bar.com
else

        echo lp queue is empty | /usr/ucb/mail foo@bar.com

fi
```

Works fine as a shell script; cron cannot cat $stuff

edit2: changed these 2, same result

```
stuff="(ls -1 /var/spool/lp/requests/localhost/ | /usr/bin/head -1)"


puff="$(cat $stuff | /usr/bin/head -1 | sed -e 's/-.*//' -e 's/$/ is having issues printing from /)"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)

Comment: No that DID NOT answer the question

Comment: *Works fine as a shell script* Huh?  On my Solaris system, it never gets past `stuff=\\\`ls -1 /var/spool/lp/requests/localhost/ | /usr/bin/head -1\\\`` - it just emits `-1: not found` with those escaped backticks in place.  And Solaris `sh` does not support `( )` as a replacement for backtick evaluation, so `stuff="(ls -1 /var/spool/lp/requests/localhost/ | /usr/bin/head -1)"` merely sets the `stuff` envval to the literal string `(ls -1 /var/spool/lp/requests/localhost/ | /usr/bin/head -1)`