# Why doesn't cron run the commands in another user's crontab?

Tags: cron, mariadb, automation, journalctl

Hello everyone and thank you in advance.

I have written a job in the mysql user crontab, but it doesn't run at all. I think  my code is correct, because it works properly if I execute it pointing to a script from my user's crontab:

```
00 12 * * * /usr/bin/mariadb-dump -u root -pMyPassword  --lock-tables -A > /full/path/"`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`".sql && rm /full/path/"`date -d '-2 days' '+%Y-%m-%d'`".sql
```

But it does not work when I point at it from the mysql user's crontab:

```
00 12 * * * /full/path/to/script
```

I have also tried running it directly escaping the % signs, but that didn't help either.

I have tried running the script with and without specifying source, even though I am not sure how that would help:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /full/path/to/my/user/.zshrc
00 12 * * * /usr/bin/mariadb-dump -u root -pMyPassword  --lock-tables -A > /full/path/"`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`".sql && rm /full/path/"`date -d '-2 days' '+%Y-%m-%d'`".sql
```

I have also added an extra blank line to the bottom of the crontab. It didn't help, and the journal doesn't tell me much.

I have also tried changing the permissions for the folder and its contents. Now, it's on 775, and I have added the mysql user to the group, but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas what might be wrong with my set-up?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)

Comment: Notably the section regarding percent signs in the linked duplicate

Comment: I read it and I tried some things, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Usually `cron` do not handle well the `&` and other symbols so the best you can do is to create script like. Also consider using absolute paths everywhere:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /your/home/directory/.bash_profile
/path/to/mariadb-dump -u root -pMyPassword  --lock-tables -A > /path/to/desired/path/"`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`".sql && rm /path/to/desired/path/"`date -d '-2 days' '+%Y-%m-%d'`".sql
```

and run it from `cron`:

```
* 12 * * * /path/to/script
```

Do not forget to make this script executable. Also run it every minute is not the wise way. Probably you want to run it once per day:

```
0 12 * * * /path/to/script
```

If you have special symbols in your password try to create file `~/.my.cnf` and add this inside:

```
[client]
# The following password is sent to all standard MySQL clients
password="my password"
```

and leave in command line just `-p` w/o password after this

Comment: Useful to improve set-up. Thanks, @Romeo. Unfortunatelly, it still threw the same error at me.

Comment: @Centaro did you test it to run the things from command line?

Comment: yes and it worked. That's why I think my code is correct.

Comment: @Centaro, will edit my script, please check

Comment: Hello again, I have tried your code, but no jobs from the mysql user crontab happen to work. The code works from my user's crontab when I point to the script, but not when I point to it from the mysql crontab. I have tried with and without the source line. Any ideas what might be going on? Thanks, everyone.

Comment: @Centaro, eventually do you have in your password symbols which may be interpreted by bash? Try to put passw0rd in `my.cnf` file in home directory (will edit my question)

Comment: The command stops working properly even from my regular user's crontab if I call the password from ~/.my.cnf 

Thank you so much, that you keep providing ideas. I will certainly try anything else you suggest. 

But also, I don't see how changing the location of the password would help getting the command to run from the mysql user's crontab. Since it works flawlessly from the regular user's crontab.

Answer (score 1):

- You need to escape `%` sings with the backslashes `\`. That's why it doesn't run the command as expected.
- It might be a good idea to use absolute paths instead of `~/relative/paths`.
- `* 12 * * *` runs the command on every minute of the hour `12`; please revise.
- Do not put the password on the command line as it will be logged and it will also be visible to every user while the command is running.

Comment: I have tried running it escaping the % signs as a cronjob and in a script the cronjob points to, but it didn't run the code. 

```
mariadb-dump -u root -pMyPassword  --lock-tables -A > /absolute/path/"`date +"\%Y-\%m-\%d"`".sql && rm /absolute/path/"`date -d '-2 days' '+\%Y-\%m-\%d'`".sql
```

I know it still has the password in it, but I will worry about that after I get it to run.

Comment: Also, when I run it from cron, I get a different log:

```
lip 21 09:19:01 T15 crond[722]: (root) CAN'T OPEN (/etc/crontab): No such file or directory
lip 21 09:19:01 T15 crond[722]: (mysql) RELOAD (/var/spool/cron/mysql)
lip 21 09:19:01 T15 crond[268631]: pam_unix(crond:session): session opened for user mysql(uid=964) by mysql(uid=0)
lip 21 09:19:02 T15 CROND[268631]: pam_unix(crond:session): session closed for user mysql
lip 21 09:19:51 T15 crontab[268660]: (root) LIST (mysql)
```