# Scheduling job on crontab with custom timing

Tags: cron, unix-shell

Can anyone help me scheduling a job on crontab that will run on 12th of each month and if 12th falls on weekends it should run on the next Monday.

I found something from Internet but it's not working

```
0 0 12 * * [ "$(date +%d -d tomorrow)" == "12" ] && [ "$(date +%u -d 12th)" -gt 5 ] && your-command
```

This is what ChatGPT gave me. I don't know how to debug this one

Comment: Your "something"is not working because `%` percent signs have special meaning in cron syntax and typically require escaping https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

Answer (score 2):

[My general recommendation](https://serverfault.com/a/815541/37681) is that when you can't trivially format your schedule with the limited syntax that cron provides, you should NOT attempt to create a really complex cron command.

As a work around: run a schedule (slightly) more frequently then you need and then in your batch job, or a wrapper shell script, where you have a much richter environment, you apply the "*complex*" logic you need. If the batch is allowed to run, execute the job and otherwise exit gracefully.

### Example

In cron schedule your batch to run from a wrapper script that always runs on days 12, 13 and 14 or allow it to even run every day.

```
# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
25 4 12,13,14 * *   /path/to/your/wrapper.script
# or even: 
25 4 * * *  /path/to/your/wrapper.script
```

And then in that wrapper shell script you apply the logic:

- IF today is the 12<sup>th</sup> AND a weekday:
  run the job ELSE exit gracefully
- IF today is the 13<sup>th</sup> AND a Monday:
  (then the 12<sup>th</sup> was a Sunday and the job wasn't allowed to run)
  run the job ELSE exit gracefully
- IF today is the 14<sup>th</sup> AND a Monday:
  (then the 12<sup>th</sup> was a Saturday and the job wasn't allowed to run)
  run the job ELSE exit gracefully

Your `/path/to/your/wrapper.script` bash script then could look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Wrapper script that will run_batch() on the 12th when 
# the 12th is a weekday, otherwise the following Monday 

run_batch () {
    # Add the real job here
    echo "The job has started"
}

TODAY=$(date +%d) 
#  date +%u     day of week (1..7); 1 is Monday
WEEKDAY=$(date +%u)  

if [ "${TODAY}" -eq 12 ] && [ "${WEEKDAY}" -le 5 ] ; then 
     run_batch
elif [ "${TODAY}" -eq  13 ] && [ "${WEEKDAY}" -eq  1 ] ; then
     run_batch
elif [ "${TODAY}" -eq 14 ] && [ "${WEEKDAY}" -eq  1 ] ; then
    run_batch
else
    exit    
fi
```